# Find next woking date from the given data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 columns named Userid and holidaydate in a table named userdays. Below is the data.

| Userid | holidaydate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-17 |
| 1 | 2023-03-21 |
| 1 | 2023-03-22 |
| 1 | 2023-03-23 |
| 1 | 2023-05-12 |
| 2 | 2023-09-15 |
| 3 | 2023-06-09 |
| 3 | 2023-06-28 |

For each user, we have to find next working day. For 2023-01-17 next work date is 2023-01-18. For 2023-03-21 next work date is 2023-03-24 because 2023-03-22 and 2023-03-23 is a holiday

I need a sql query for below output:

| Userid | nextworkdate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-18 |
| 1 | 2023-03-24 |
| 1 | 2023-03-24 |
| 1 | 2023-03-24 |
| 1 | 2023-05-13 |
| 2 | 2023-09-16 |
| 3 | 2023-06-10 |
| 3 | 2023-06-29 |

Comment: Could you please tag the RDBMS you are using ?

Comment: Are we to assume that if a date isn't in the holiday table it's a "Working" date?  Meaning weekends are "working" days or do we need to verify the next date is also not a weekend?  This seems like it will be an island and gap problem...

Comment: What about weekends, business holidays, etc?

Comment: 1) Updated the tag to sql server management studio. 
2) Given holidays dates are the only holidays that we have to consider

Comment: What did you do to solve this problem? (besides asking) Where (or why) did your attempt fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a window function solution to get the next workday:

```sql
select *
,   COALESCE(nextnonholiday, min(nextnonholiday) over(partition by userid order by holidaydate rows between 1 following and unbounded following), dateadd(day, 1, holidaydate)) as nextWorkDay
from (
    select *, case when lead(holidaydate) over(partition by userid order by holidaydate) <> dateadd(day, 1, holidaydate) then dateadd(day, 1, holidaydate) end as nextNonHoliday
    from (
        VALUES  (1, N'2023-01-17')
        ,   (1, N'2023-03-21')
        ,   (1, N'2023-03-22')
        ,   (1, N'2023-03-23')
        ,   (1, N'2023-05-12')
        ,   (2, N'2023-09-15')
        ,   (3, N'2023-06-09')
        ,   (3, N'2023-06-28')
    ) t (Userid,holidaydate)
    ) x
order by userid, holidaydate
```

First you check if next non-holiday is same as next day, if not that's the value we want, otherwise we go to the next step.

In the next step, we get the first non-holiday date that we previously calculated in a "following" window function, ie. we basically look ahead and take the first non-holiday date from the table.

Answer (score 1):

If weekends and business holidays don't interest you, this might be helpful :

```
with c1 as (
  select Userid, holidaydate, DATEADD(day, 1, holidaydate) as nextdate
  from mytable
),
c2 as (
  select Userid, nextdate
  from c1
  where nextdate not in (
    select distinct holidaydate
    from c1
  )
)
select Userid, (
        SELECT
            MIN(c2.nextdate)
        FROM c2
        WHERE c2.nextdate >= c1.nextdate
            AND c1.Userid = c2.Userid
    ) AS nextworkdate
from c1
```

Explanations :

C1 retrieves the `nextdate` by adding 1 day to the `holidaydate`.

C2 retrieves potential `nextworkdate` by excluding holidays.

Results :

```
Userid  nextworkdate
1       2023-01-18
1       2023-03-24
1       2023-03-24
1       2023-03-24
1       2023-05-13
2       2023-09-16
3       2023-06-10
3       2023-06-29
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/uvseYK52)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
with cte as
(

    SELECT
        (FORMAT(nextworkdate, 'ddd')) as days, nextworkdate
    from Table_1
) 
  select 
  case 
    when cte.days='sat' or cte.days='sun' then DATEADD(DAY, 2, nextworkdate)
  else DATEADD(DAY, 1, nextworkdate)
  end 
  from cte
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**